# Regular Expressions match any string between [ and ]

Tags: c#

I want to match any string between [ and ]. Following code working fine but i want to output with out this symbol [ ]

my code:

```
    string strValue = "{test}dfdgf[sms]";// i want to sms

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Match mtch = Regex.Match(strValue, @"\[((\s*?.*?)*?)\]");
        if (mtch.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mtch.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is also a [generic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77143985/2638227) to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use [Match.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) property.  Since you are already using brackets, you can get the group you want with

```
MessageBox.Show(mtch.Groups[1].Value);
```

Groups[0] will contain the whole string with the [ and ].

Also, I think your regex can be simplified

```
\[((\s*?.*?)*?)\]
```

should be equivalent to

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

since .* will match anything, including white space, which is what \s covers.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MessageBox.Show(mtch.Groups[1].Value);
```

This gives you the value of the first captured group - the contents of the outer parantheses.