# How to extract all strings between brackets using c#?

Tags: c#, split

If I have a string such as:

"You id is (1) and your number is (0000000000)"

What is the best way to extract these these strings into a list of strings. The numbers between the brackets can increase in digits thus searching for the strings between the brackets is a better technique.

I can use the code below to extract the first string between brackets.

```
var myString = "You id is (1) and your number is (0000000000)";
var firstNumberBetweenBrackets = myString.Split('(', ')')[1]; // would return 1
```

Comment: mystring would be the one listed: "You id is (1) and your number is (0000000000)"

Comment: Yeah, I could put in 3 to return the second number between brackets. But I wanted a better way. That was more logical and only returned strings between the brackets

Comment: @Benl2 If you need to only grab digit chunks from inside parentheses, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48973456/3832970).

Comment: I selected the Linq answer as the initial run of both answers showed that linq was faster and more efficient than using the regex. In terms of a duplicate, the associated question answered for a single piece of text between parentheses. I had already reviewed the question, thus I provided the solution to extracting one string in my question. It did not supply an answer to my specific question.

Comment: I really do not understand why this question is marked as duplicate, which reminds me that SO should have a way to challenge duplicate markings which sometimes are exaggerated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a LINQ solution:

```
var result = myString.Split().Where(x => x.StartsWith("(") && x.EndsWith(")")).ToList();
```

Values stored in `result`:

```
result[0] = (1)
result[1] = (0000000000)
```

And if you want only the numbers without the brackets use:

```
var result = myString.Split().Where(x => x.StartsWith("(") && x.EndsWith(")"))
                     .Select(x=>x.Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty))
                     .ToList();
```

Values stored in `result`:

```
result[0] = 1
result[1] = 0000000000
```

Comment: this is not working for me, is returning an empty list

Comment: this answer does not cover all cases, for example in my case it work for many cases but does not work for `(12345)=1`

Comment: **INFORMATIONAL** There's one overload of `Trim` method that takes user defined characters to `Trim` around text. So your second query can also be written like this:
    `char[] brackets = { '(', ')' };`
`var result = myString.Split().Where(x => x.StartsWith("(") && x.EndsWith(")")).Select(x => x.Trim(brackets)).ToList();`

Comment: incorrect if date inside brackets: "[2022-03-14 14:00:36.767] [1] [Information] [PostInstallTool.App.GetMsiConfigPaths] Reading configuration from: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Nuance\\ControlSuite\\Configuration\\ComponentProviders"

Comment: Nice solution but does not work in some cases, when one of the brackets is adjacent for example. Try with this: "You id is(1) ..." It ignores the adjacent bracket.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Regex for this (https://regex101.com/r/T4Sdik/1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(([^()]+)\)*");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches("You id is (1) and your number is (0000000000)")
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

This will print:

```
1
0000000000
```

Comment: Glad I helped !

Comment: Does this not print the numbers with the brackets?

Comment: No, you asked to extract the numbers between the brackets.

Comment: If you want them with the brackets you can either add them or change the regex to `(\([^()]+\))`.

Comment: Yeah ive tested your code and its printing the brackets aswell

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to get strings of digits inside parentheses, you may use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\((\d+)\)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

The results are in Group 1, so you need to access them with `m.Groups[1].Value`.

**Regex details**

- `\(` - matches a literal `(`
- `(\d+)` - [Capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1: one or more (due to the `+` quantifier) digits (you may use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` to only match ASCII digits, or use the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`)
- `\)` - a literal `)`

See the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/cDtLAK) and a [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%28%28%5Cd%2B%29%5C%29&i=You%20id%20is%20%281%29%20and%20your%20number%20is%20%280000000000%29%20and%20%28word%29%20here):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answers are already good but it might be useful to provide a **generic method for general data (numeric or text) and different brackets**:

```
IEnumerable<string> ExtractBracketsContent(
    char openingBracket,
    char closingBracket,
    string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
    // Use "\" to escape the brackets
    string pattern = string.Format(@"\{0}(.*?)\{1}", openingBracket, closingBracket);
    var result = Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);

    return result;
}
```

That is, you can *specify the opening and closing brackets*. To use:

```
string text = "Your ID is (abc) and your number is (123)";
var contents = ExtractBracketsContent('(', ')', text); // Returns abc, 123
```

To use it with square (or curly etc.) brackets:

```
string text = "Your ID is [abc] and your number is [123]";
var contents = ExtractBracketsContent('[', ']', text); // Returns abc, 123
```