# How to use regex to extract a string with multiple curly braces?

Tags: c#

I have this sample string

```
`{1:}{2:}{3:}{4:\r\n-}{5:}`
```

and I want to extract out only `{4:\r\n-}`

This is my code but it is not working.

```
var str = "{1:}{2:}{3:}{4:\r\n-}{5:}";
var regex = new Regex(@"{4:*.*-}");
var match = regex.Match(str);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: There is also a [generic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77143985/2638227) to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the special regex characters (in this case the opening and closing braces and the backslashes) in the search string. This would capture just that part:

```
var regex = new Regex("\{4:\\r\\n-\}");
```

... or if you wanted anything up to and including the slash before the closing brace (which is what it looks like you might be trying to do)...

```
var regex = new Regex("\{4:[^-]*-\}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape your `\r` and `\n` characters in your regular expression. You can use the [Regex.Escape()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-6.0) method to escape characters in your regex string which returns a string of characters that are converted to their escaped form.

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6GLZrl

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = @"{1:}{2:}{3:}{4:\r\n-}{5:}";
        string regex = @"{4:\r\n-}";  //Original regex
        Match m = Regex.Match(str, Regex.Escape(regex));
        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);        
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No match found");        
        }
    }
}
```